# rubyのclass内で共通のオブジェクトを使いたい

Tags: ruby

rubyのclass内で共通のオブジェクトを使用するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。
クラスメソッドに定義したいので、initializeを使わない方法を教えて下さい。

イメージとしては以下のような感じです。

```
class Hoge

  @obj = Fuga.new

  def self.test
    @obj.abcd
  end
  def self.test2
    @obj.efg
  end

end
```

Comment: クラス変数の事でしょうか？ それでしたら、`@@obj = Fuga.new` などとします(先頭に `@@` を付けます)。

Comment: 例示されたコードで特に問題ないと思うのですが、これだと何か問題あったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

質問で書かれているコードでも良さそうですが、オブジェクトを取得するクラスメソッドを定義し、その中で遅延初期化のイディオムを使うと、なんとなくお行儀が良い気がします。

```
class Bar
  def initialize
    puts 'Initialized.'
  end

  def hello
    puts 'Hello'
  end

  def bye
    puts 'Bye'
  end
end

class Foo
  def self.hello
    bar.hello
  end

  def self.bye
    bar.bye
  end

  def self.bar
    @bar ||= Bar.new
  end
end

# クラスメソッドの呼び出し
Foo.hello
# => Initialized.
# => Hello

Foo.bye
# => Bye
```